# How to retrieve data from UsageStats found in Android Settings?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I am using API 19. For my app that i am building, i need to obtain the usage pattern of each app on my device (i.e. hwo many times have you used since installation...and how many times you open it)
I cam across this feature called UsageStats provided in my phone under the android settings at location com.android.settings/.UsageStats 
Now i need to retrieve those data to my application for analysis by my own-app,

I referred various contents from satckoverflow (sorry..i dont have API 21) but they were not as informative.
[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22DNt.png)
[screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvunk.png)